How to read one line at a time, do math on the line and write back to a file
I have a csv or txt file with
2.3   4.5    5.6   8

1.2   3.5    7.4   2

...and so on for thousands of lines.
I want to be able to read line by line and do some math (let's say multiply the third column by -1) and write it all back to an output file. I don't want to read everything into one array as I'll be dealing with very large files.
This is what I have so far, and it's close, but it doesn't like Row being a tuple and not an integer for the math.
def applymath(self):
    with open(self.path_name2[0]) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        self.textEdit_2.setText("")
        g = open(self.savefile1[0], "w")
        for row in reader:
            row[:, 2] = row[:, 2] * -1
            self.textEdit_2.append((str(row[0])).lstrip('[').rstrip(']'))
            print(((str(row[0])).lstrip('[').rstrip(']')), file=g)


Well, don't use numpy/pandas. Those are designed to handle all rows at once. Use the csv module and a loop.

What do you mean by large files? GB of data is not really an issue for Pandas to handle.  Also if it is in scientific notation, you can simply reformat to the format you want.

You will find help here provided you respect this site rules. You have correctly stated the general context (handle a big file one line at a time), but you have failed to show a honest attempt. We insist in having some code, because 1/ it is much easier for a answerer to stick to your usages (variable names, etc...) if you have shown your code and 2/ you will learn much more by first trying smth and then asking here and explaining where you are stuck than by directly receiving a piece of code. TL/DR: please show your current best attempt.

You can also read the file line by line and then parse each line yourself.

This question is similar to: How do I read and write CSV files?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can use pandas to deal with such tasks.
For example, I created an input_data.txt following your format
df = pd.read_csv("input_data.txt"
            # Each value is separated by space
            , delimiter = " "
            # Given there is no header/column names
            , header=None)
df.head()

Multiply the 3rd column by -1
df[2] = df[2] * -1

Write the new data frame with the same format
df.to_csv("Data/output_data.txt"
            # Each value is separated by space
            , sep = " "
            # Keep the same format with no header/column names
            , header = None
            # Remove dataframe index
            , index = False)


hey thanks for the reply but this is reading all the data into one array.  I know this will bog down with the file sizes I'll be dealing with.  I'm trying to read one line at a time, do the math and write that line to a file

How do you know it will 'bog down'? Pandas will have no trouble with a million lines and will be faster than you reading in each line at a time, parsing it, changing a column and writing out.

actually yeah, this might be key!  it's super fast actually, thanks so much, guys!

To avoid reading the entire file into memory, process one line at a time and write the output to a new (temporary) file. When you've finished processing all lines, rename the temporary file
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

SOURCE = Path("foo.txt")

with SOURCE.open() as s:
    with NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", delete=False, delete_on_close=False, dir=SOURCE.parent) as t:
        tname = t.name
        for line in s:
            values = list(map(float, line.split()))
            if len(values) > 2:
                values[2] *= -1
                print(*values, file=t)
            else:
                print(line, file=t, end="")
SOURCE.unlink() # only really necessary on Windows
Path(tname).rename(SOURCE)

Note:
Specifying dir in the NamedTemporaryFile constructor can improve performance when/if the source file's location and default temporary directories are on different filesystems. In such a case the rename operation is performed by copying one file to the other. For very large files this might be slow. If we create the temporary file in the same directory as the source file the rename will be atomic
